# How can I use login.blade.php in a React homepage component?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I know this is a weird question, but I'm going to explain:
I have a full working Laravel project (homepage and dashboard for users,clients ecc..).
I rebuilt the homepage with React but for the login and dashboard I want to use php blades ecc... that I have already in Laravel without change anything.
(React is included already in Laravel project)

Now, I need only one thing, when I click login on React header navigation I'd like to render only the laravel code below as a modal, over my React Homepage, without @extends('layout.home') because now it shows me the old Laravel homepage with the login.
How can I achieve that?
Because I don't want to set up a new form in React with handle submit and js-cookies ecc.... everything working already in Laravel blades.

Thanks

```
@extends('layout.home')

 @section('content')
  <div class="loginImg">

<img class="loginImg__img" src={{ asset("images/public/pages/authentification.jpg") }}>

<form class="loginImg__form" method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}" aria-label="Login">
    @csrf

    <div class="form__details">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required="" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>

    <div class="form__details">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">

        <a class="heading-8" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
            Forgot Your Password?
        </a>

        <input type="submit" class="form__submit" value="Log in">

        <div class="form__group__join">

            <p class="heading-8">Not registered yet? Sign up </p>
            <a class="heading-8" href="{{ route('register') }}">here<span>!</span></a>

        </div>

    </div>

</form>

<img class="logo_white" src="{{ asset("images/logos/logo_white.png") }}">

 </div>
   @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JWT auth see more details here 
https://medium.com/@Gbxnga/token-based-authentication-with-react-and-laravel-restful-api-83f16581e85

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I need a different approach. As I said I want to use the login.blade I have already in Laravel, not a login form in React.